# how to name an object reference (handle) dynamically in ruby

Tags: ruby, object, reference

So I have a class like this:

```
def Word


end
```

and im looping thru an array like this

```
array.each do |value|

end
```

And inside that loop I want to instantiate an object, with a handle of the var

```
value = Word.new
```

Im sure there is an easy way to do this - I just dont know what it is!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand. You say you "want to instantiate an object with a handle of the var," but that doesn't mean anything to me. If you can't clarify what that means, can you at least explain what effect you expect it to have?

Comment: you create a class using `class Word; end` not `def Word; end`

Comment: yes, thanks - that was the result of being new to ruby and being somewhat brain fried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign things to a dynamic variable name, you need to use something like `eval`:

```
array.each do |value|
  eval "#{value} = Word.new"
end
```

but check this is what you want - you should avoid using `eval` to solve things that really require different data structures, since it's hard to debug errors created with eval, and can easily cause undesired behaviour. For example, what you might really want is a hash of words and associated objects, for example

```
words = {}    
array.each do |value|
  words[value] = Word.new
end
```

which won't pollute your namespace with tons of `Word` objects.

Comment: Absolutely don't do the first one unless you want to cause yourself a lot of extra trouble.

Comment: Ahh thanks Peter and Chuck. I didn't think of doing it that way. Yes Ill stick with the second one - it looks alot smarter and actually will allow me to do more. 

I just needed a way to have each of my "values" (which are vars) to be a Word object. A hash of values wouldnt work because I needed methods as well as values. So A hash of Objects - brillant - thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the data structure you want to work with, you could also do this:

```
# will give you an array:
words = array.map { |value| Word.new(value) }

# will give you a hash (as in Peter's example)
words = array.inject({}) { |hash, value| hash.merge value => Word.new }

# same as above, but more efficient, using monkey-lib (gem install monkey-lib)
words = array.construct_hash { |value| [value, Word.new ] }
```